# let suggestion list pop up when entering the field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have made a field with an autosuggestion.
I set minLength to 0;

When I enter the textfield, I need to press a non-char key (i.e. arrow-down-key) to get the unfiltered full list of options.

I want this behaviour when I enter the field without pressing a key.
I tried the following in my  onFocus() event:

```
 $('myinput').autocomplete( "search" );
```

But that just does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in the past.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/D9XwN/)

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    minLength:0,
    source: ["one","two","three"]
    }).on("focus", function () { $(this).autocomplete("search"); });​
```